# How do I make div refresh when rotating mobile (portrait to landscape or vice versa)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have made a nav menu divided in to two (Left and Right) and I have a hide/show navigation toggle button in the middle.

The nav bar seams to behave like I want. But when I check with mobile and rotate the device from portrait to landscape or vice versa. The nav did not response. Ie the menu in the navigation go outside the screen or otherwise in wrong place.
**I did fix that with a media query**
But I have exactly same code (width:100%) in the media query as in the style sheet elsewhere. And it **does not matter what max-width** I use.

At least not for the navigation to behave correctly. My first idea was to make a reponsive website without any media queries at all. I failed in the early stage :))
It seams like now when I have a media query, the browser go and check the width of the screen if it chaanges, or something like this.

Sorry for long introduction.. now I need your help

- Can there be some problems with my media query I use?
- Do you have an
  option to offer?
- What width do you recomend or does it not matter?

Please check my code:
CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2767px) {
    .nav {
        width:100%;
    }
    .hidden {
        display:none;
    }
    .normal {
        display:block;
    }
    .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .navtog {
        position:fixed;
        z-index:1500;
        left:50%;
        top:25px;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .nav {
        font: 120% oswald;
        color:#fff;
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
        z-index:1050;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .nav_r {
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:10%;
    }
    .nav_l {
        padding-left:10%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
```

HTML and JS

```
<script>
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        e.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
</script>

<div class="center">
    <div class="navtog"> 
        <a onclick="toggle_visibility('navbar');" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <img src="img/toggle.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="navbar" class="hidden nav">
    <div class="nav_r">navigation items Right</div>
    <div class="nav_l">navigation items Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also use   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your media query applies to all screen sizes up to 2767px (so basically all). Media queries in a mobile-first approach usually include `min-width` instead, so that different things happen at very small sizes than at larger, tablet sizes. Try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    ...
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/etLpyaft/)**

You may need to reverse more of your display properties to get it working as you intend, but the breakpoint should typically be between your portrait and landscape widths.

Comment: My code seams to work no matter what width i use in the query. It is there for the browser to refresh the div on turning the device screen.

Comment: I understand i explained with bad grammar. Apologies for that.

Comment: I would like to have an optional way. Than media queries

Comment: Media queries is the right way to do this. There's no need to "refresh" anything.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time. I appreciate. Sorry for bothering. I thought these media queries make the site slower...